# How to check object property empty value in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

To create a function to determine an object's property is empty or contain double quote as below

Code## Heading ##

```
private ReturlFalseIfObjectPropertiesEmpty(a) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames != undefined ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a).length != 0 : (
      function() {
         for (const key in a) return (key != undefined) && (key != "");
      }) ();
    }
```

Data that I need to validat

### Heading

```
const data = [{"employeeContact": {
        "personalPhone": "",
        "workPhone": "",
        "personalEmail": "",
        "workEmail": "",
        "currentAddress": "",
        "permanentAddress": ""
      }}
    ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to check for an empty value or an empty string in an Object through these suggested methods:

> **NOTE:** All of these results shows a new an array of object with properties that doesn't have an empty value or ''
>
> If you would like to have its result otherwise, showing the fields that has an empty value or '', you can change the conditions below from **value != ''** to **value == ''** to give you your desired results.

**Sample Data**

```
const data = [{"employeeContact": {
    "personalPhone": "",
    "workPhone": "",
    "personalEmail": "",
    "workEmail": "",
    "currentAddress": "sample",      // Supplied one with a value
    "permanentAddress": ""
  }}
];
```

**Method #1 - Use the ES7 For Loop with Object.entries**

```
const employeeContract = data[0].employeeContact;
let result = [];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(employeeContract)) {
  if (value != '') result.push({ [key]: value });   // This will push a new object with its existing key and assign its value if the object is not empty. Ex. { personalPhone: 'sample'}
}

console.log(result);   // [ { currentAddress: 'sample' } ]
```

**Method #2 - Filter with ES7 Object.entries (Simplified)**

```
const employeeContract = data[0].employeeContact;
const result = Object.entries(employeeContract).filter(([key, value]) => value != '' ? { [key]: value } : null);

console.log(result);   // [ { currentAddress: 'sample' } ]
```

---

To use Object.entries in Typescript, you will need to edit your **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",        // Use es2017 to use all of its features
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}

// Or if you are using ES6 and you only want to use the ES7 Object.entries() feature then, just supply values on the "lib" property
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017.object"]   // Add this line to enable using Object.entries()
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: .entries does not existing Typescript

Comment: @HengSopheak had updated my comment on how to enable Object.entries on your ts files through editing the target or lib property in tsconfig.json